# Can we change the icon and name of shortcut created in iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios7

In my app am creating the shortcut through an api. I need to change the image and name of created shortcuts. The functionality is these shortcuts will take you back into the app and show the profile of a particular user. So, is it possible to change the icon and name of that shortcut programmatically? I googled this and found that I can not change the icon and name of app but can change the name for shortcut created.
Please guide for above.
Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Filling the form including user's name phone number and other details with the profile picture. Then only profile picture and name is sent to server and links the app to safari where app name is saved and then shortcut is created on the home page, then when we click that shortcut the app is linked directly to the profile of that user which is created. I want to know if we provide the same data to the api again can the safari update the shortcut name and profile pic. If anyone has worked on any such thing then please respond.

Comment: What do you mean by shortcut here? Provide much more info related to flow and if you add relative screenshots, then it would be much better.

Answer (score -1):

Because you can't programmatically create shortcuts (i.e. it has to be done by the user through the web browser), you can't retain references to those and change them programatically.

What you can do, however, is [update the icon image on the web page](https://gigaom.com/2011/06/22/how-to-create-ios-device-home-screen-icons-for-web-sites/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+TheAppleBlog+%28GigaOM%3A+Apple%29/). This will only update when the user clicks on the shortcut again, but it's the best you'll get.